# Resizing the Bitmap in Android

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to simply resize my bitmap which i am getting from the following class named Image Loader (Using Lazy Loadng scheme). I want to simply cut short my image size to 60*60 size. But when i use -

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 20, 25, false);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

It does the same as I want but the bitmap that comes out is very very blurred. Is there any other way to implement the same.

Here is my Image Loader class in BITMAP dISPLAYER(iNNER cLASS) Where i am setting the image by the code I have shown above.

```
package com.irant.LazyLoading;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

import com.irant.a1techno.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.widget.ImageView;



public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = new ConcurrentHashMap<ImageView, String>();

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        //Make the background thead low priority. This way it will not affect the UI performance
        photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-1);

        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
    }

    final int stub_id=R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    public void displayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
        {
            //bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 25, 25, true);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
        else
        {

            queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }    
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
    {
        //This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them. 
        photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
        }

        //start thread if it's not started yet
        if(photoLoaderThread.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)
            photoLoaderThread.start();
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);
        InputStream is;
        //from SD cache
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {

            System.out.println("---------------------IMAGE URL: "+url);

            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = ShrinkBitmap(url, 60, 60);
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, baos);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("---------------------IMAGE URL: "+url);
            ex.printStackTrace();
            //stopThread();
            return null;

        }
        finally{
            bitmap = null;
            is=null;
        }
    }

    Bitmap ShrinkBitmap(String file, int width, int height){

        BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);

        int heightRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight/(float)height);
        int widthRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth/(float)width);

        if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1)
        {
            if (heightRatio > widthRatio)
            {
                bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
            } else {
                bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio; 
            }
        }

        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);
        return bitmap;
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } 
        catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    PhotosQueue photosQueue=new PhotosQueue();

    public void stopThread()
    {
        photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
    }

    //stores list of photos to download
    class PhotosQueue
    {
        private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad=new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

        //removes all instances of this ImageView
        public void Clean(ImageView image)
        {
            for(int j=0 ;j<photosToLoad.size();){
                if(photosToLoad.get(j).imageView==image)
                    photosToLoad.remove(j);
                else
                    ++j;
            }
        }
    }

    public class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true)
                {
                    //thread waits until there are any images to load in the queue
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()==0)
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                        }
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()!=0)
                    {
                        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photoToLoad=photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
                        }
                        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
                        if(tag!=null && tag.equals(photoToLoad.url)){
                            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad.imageView);
                            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                        }
                    }
                    if(Thread.interrupted())
                        break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //allow thread to exit
                System.out.println("This is the Exit Point............");
            }
        }
    }

    PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread=new PhotosLoader();

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ImageView imageView;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i){bitmap=b;imageView=i;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(bitmap!=null)
            {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 20, 25, false);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            else
                imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }



}
```

Please reply me.
Thanks in advance

Please dont down the vote if you don't understand. Just help me if anybody can.

Thanks

Comment: If you want it to be 60*60, why are you scaling it to 20*25? perhaps that's why it is blurry?

Comment: I was just trying with 20*25 that if it is still blurred or not. Even If I scale it to 10*10. It shows a blurred image.

Comment: I'm just saying that depending on the Imageview's scaleType, if you put in an image smaller than the imageview itself, it will stretch that image to fill its bounds - just ensuring that you had tried 60*60 or however big you imageview actually is

Comment: Here is my image view code where i am attaching it.

<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_GridItem"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:background="@drawable/pic_frame_bg" />

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `scaleType` of an `ImageView` is `FIT_CENTER`, meaning that whatever Image you give to the `ImageView` will be scaled so that one of the axis will be (in your case) 110dp.  So passing it a bitmap that has been scaled down to 10*10 will stretch that bitmap to fill the 110*110 space, and a 10*10 stretched that big will be very blurry indeed.  Try using one of the other `scaleType`s, specifically `CENTER` to see the unblurred, normal sized version of the image:

```
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
```

If this isn't the effect you want, know that no matter what you do, shrinking an image and then stretching it back out again will always make it a lower quality than what you started with.  A lot of what you seem to be trying to do in the code sample above has been done for you by the `ImageView` class itself - I would encourage you to take a closer look at the `ScaleType`s and what they can do for you

Comment: Now I am using this code as per your recommendation..


imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER); 
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 20, 25, false); 
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


After using this I am getting no Image on the ImageView, only background frame is there which I have addded in the imageview background. Please help me Raymond. I am in big problem regarding the same. Thanks

Comment: I have to admit I've never heard of that before - you might be better off asking it as another question, sorry :(

Comment: Its Ok Raymond. Thanks anyways :)